# Is it possible to execute two functions at EXACTLY the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm wanting to take photos from 2 different cameras at exactly the same time (or as close as possible).

If I use multithreading or multiprocessing, it still runs the threads/processes consecutively.. For instance if I start the following processes:

```
Take_photo_1.start()
Take_photo_2.start()
```

While those processes would run in parallel, the commands to start the processes are still executed sequentially. Is there any way to execute both those processes at exactly the same time?

Comment: Yes (for small values of "as close as possible).  For cameras, traditionally you'd use some kind of triggering system, but using your model you could have a shared variable that registers callbacks, or have them on loops checking wall time. It depends on what kind of resolution of "exactly" you're expecting

Comment: It'd be relatively easy to have an Arduino electronically activate two cable releases simultaneously in hardware on receipt of, say, a command you could send serially down the USB cable from your controlling PC to the Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to make this *exact* even if you're writing directly in machine code. Even if you have all the threads wait on a kernel barrier, that wait can take different times on different cores, and there are opcodes to process between the barrier wait and the camera get that have to get fetched and run on a system where the caches may be in different states, and there's nothing stopping the OS from stealing the CPU from one of the threads to run some completely unrelated code, and the I/O to the camera (even if it isn't serialized, which it may be) probably isn't a guaranteed static time, and so on.

When you throw an interpreted language on top of it (especially one with a GIL, like Python, which means the bytecodes between the barrier wait and the camera get can't be run in parallel)… well, you're not really changing anything; "impossible * 7" is still "impossible". But you are making it even more obvious.

Fortunately, very few real-life problems have a true hard real-time requirement like that. Instead, you have a requirement like "99.9% of the time, all camera gets should happen within +/-4ms of the desired exact 30fps". Or, maybe, "90% of the time it's within +/-1ms, 99.9% of the time it's within +/-4ms, 99.999% of the time it's within +/-20ms, as long as you don't do anything stupid like change the wall-power state of the laptop while running the code".

Or… well, only you know why you wanted "exact", and can figure out what the actual requirements are that would satisfy you.

And for that case, often the simplest thing to do is write the code the obvious way, stress test the hell out of it, see if it meets your requirements, and figure out how to optimize things only if it doesn't.

So, your existing code may well be fine.

If not, adding a shared `barrier = threading.Barrier()` and doing a `barrier.wait()` right before the `camera.get()` may be all you need.

You may need to add logic to detect timer lag and re-synchronize (which you might do independently in each thread, or have whichever thread gets there first compute it and just make everyone else wait at the barrier).

You may need to rewrite the core loop in C. Or dump whichever OS you're using for one with better real-time guarantees like QNX. Or throw out the OS entirely so there's no scheduler to get in the way. Or throw out the complex superscalar CPUs and implement the whole thing as a hardware state machine. Or…

But, assuming you have reasonable requirements in the first place, you usually don't have to go very far.

Comment: that was very helpful. Thank you for the detailed explanation.